# Ajax counter breaks my code - why?

Tags: php, ajax

I have built a little counter in Ajax which doesn't work.  The Ajax counter breaks the entire code; even another function that doesn't rely on the counter stops working once the counter is added to the `<script>` element.
**Why does my counter break the code?**

Here is the Ajax code:

```
//My attempt at a counter.  This breaks the code.
var indx=0;
calcIndex(){
  return indx++;
}

function ajax2(){...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
var indx=0;
calcIndex(){
  return indx++;
}
```

with

```
var indx=0;
function calcIndex(){
  return indx++;
}
```